# Thighter bound than Chebyshev for the error of an estimator

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, asymptotics, upper-lower-bounds, moment-generating-functions

I have seen Chebyshev inequality applied to bound the error of an estimator wrt to its expected value. For example, the estimator of the mean of a set of values after they have been protected with a differentially private mechanism (see page 2 [here](http://www.gautamkamath.com/CS860notes/lec3.pdf)). These resources often give asymptotic bounds for the number of samples required to obtain an accurate estimate.

In [here](http://www.gautamkamath.com/CS860notes/lec3.pdf), they also mention that one can obtain similar bounds using the Chernoff inequality (I presume sharper ones). I can see how to do that for the specific r.v. in the pdf. However, how can one use Chernoff when the r.v. is not as simple?

In my case, I do not have a Bernoulli r.v. but a more complex r.v. Instead, I have the product of a Bernoulli and two Rademacher mutually independent r.v.'s (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4426470/moment-generating-function-of-product-of-rademacher-and-bernoulli)). The corresponding generating function is

$$M_{\tilde{\mu}}(t)=M_X(t)M_{X'}(-t)$$

where

$$M_X(t)=(a+\frac{1-a}{2}(e^{\lambda t}+e^{-\lambda t}))^{n}\prod_{i=1}^n(1-a+a((1-\gamma_i)e^{\lambda t}+\gamma_i e^{-\lambda t}))$$

$$M_X'(t)=(a+\frac{1-a}{2}(e^{\lambda t}+e^{-\lambda t}))^{n}\prod_{i=1}^n(1-a+a((1-\gamma_i')e^{\lambda t}+\gamma_i' e^{-\lambda t}))$$

$$\gamma_i = \frac{1+v_i(2b-1)}{2}\quad\gamma_i' = \frac{1+v_i'(2b-1)}{2}$$

$$\lambda = \frac{1}{a(2b-1)n}$$

$$0\leq a,b\leq 1$$

$$-1\leq v_i, v_i' \leq 1\quad \forall i=1,\ldots n$$

I know that the generic Chernoff inequality gives

$$\Pr[|\tilde{\mu}-\mu|<a] \leq 1 - \frac{1}{e^{at}}(\frac{M_{\tilde{\mu}}(-t)}{e^{-\mu t}} + \frac{M_{\tilde{\mu}}(t)}{e^{\mu t}})$$

If I call $\frac{1}{\alpha} = \frac{1}{e^{at}}(\frac{M_{\tilde{\mu}}(-t)}{e^{-\mu t}} + \frac{M_{\tilde{\mu}}(t)}{e^{\mu t}})$, then I should be able to obtain an asymptotic bound of this form:

$$|\tilde{\mu}-\mu| < \mathcal O(\log(f(n)))$$

However, I get lost in the asymptotic analysis of the moment generating function. My best analysis assumes $\gamma_i=\gamma_i'=\frac{1}{2}$ and gives:

$\mathcal O(M_{\tilde{\mu}}(t)) = \mathcal O(M_{\tilde{\mu}}(-t)) \in \mathcal O((e^{1/n} + e^{-1/n})^{4n})$ and so $|\tilde{\mu}-\mu| < \mathcal O(n)$.

But that doesn't make sense because the error should decrease as $n\to \infty$.

Comment: Can you give some context behind where these particular generating functions come from?

Comment: Yes, I'll edit the question.

Comment: I've edited it. The MGFs come from the product of a Bernoulli and two Rademacher r.v.'s.